# Difference between Variable Speed Compressor and Variable Speed Condenser(Fan controlled)?

Tags: thermodynamics

Are these pieces of equipment independent from each other, or one requires also the other one to be in a system (chiller)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are 2 distinct pieces of equipment that both utilize variable speed drives. and one is not a requirement for the other.

The compressor is used to adjust the pressure/flow rate of the working fluid in the system, adding a variable speed drive gives highly efficient control over this. This can make the system more efficient at part load.

At the condenser the variable speed drive controls fans that pass air (not the working fluid) over an atmospheric heat exchanger, effectively allowing you to alter its thermal conductivity. This gives additional control over the temperature at the condenser exit.

Comment: In the modeling phase of these compressors, what is the difference then? How can I model a variable compressor compared to a fixed one, so that it is more efficient at the part load? Should it be the compressor polynomials which make the difference? I would think, for instance, that the fixed speed compressor can not utilize the variable speed condenser fans?